# How to assign variables in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, task

So I have a few async methods in a xamarin Android app that will return Task<SomeClass>.

I am trying to call multiple async methods using Task.WhenAll.
I am using task.WhenAll so that it will execute the methods in parallel.
also, I am calling the method from onCreate so I am trying to keep the method synchronous by using Task.WhenAll().ContinueWith();

So in my activity, I have

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.content);

        LoadAsyncData();
    }

    private void LoadAsyncData()
    {
        Task.WhenAll(
        AsyncDataBase.SelectClass1(),
        AsyncDataBase.SelectClass2().ContinueWith(t =>{}));
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is this

```
    private void LoadAsyncData()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1() 
        Class2 c2= new Class2() 

        Task.WhenAll(
        c1 = AsyncDataBase.SelectClass1(),
        c2 = AsyncDataBase.SelectClass2().ContinueWith(t =>{}));
    }
```

However it complains that I cannot convert system threading tasks to MyClass,
Note that I am trying to keep the method synchronous as I want to call it from OnCreate.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just write:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.content);

    LoadAsyncData();
}

private async Task LoadAsyncData()
{
    var tc1 = AsyncDataBase.SelectClass1();
    var tc2 = AsyncDataBase.SelectClass2();
    var c1 = await tc1;
    var c2 - await tc2;
    //Whatever was going in `ContinueWith`
}
```

Now `LoadAsyncData` will run synchronously up until the first point when it encounters an incomplete observable. This will probably be when we `await tc1`. If you're exceptionally (un-)lucky then both async calls will actually complete before we reach their respective `await`s and so the entire code will run synchronously. However, this is usually more desirable if the additional work to be done is also more I/O related than CPU related and can also benefit from async.

Only if it's CPU bound and shouldn't block `OnCreate` from completing should you consider launching a new task at that point using `Task.Run()`.

This does leave you with the problem of an unobserved `Task` in `OnCreate`. If you're only concerned with any exceptions that may be thrown in the rest of your code, even based on your `ContinueWith` form, you'll need to have installed an [`UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event *anyway* so this shouldn't change things much.